# How to achieve Zero down time deployment using Chef?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, chef-infra

I am looking for a zero downtime deployment chef recipe where I can deploy my java/ROR application on my server with out down time ?

Please suggest me the steps to follow to achieve Zero down time deployment both in java & ROR enviroment with examples ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to think bigger picture than configuration management to embrace zero downtime deployments. Think of the web traffic going to your application as a stream of water and your application as a bucket. You can't perform maintenance on the bucket while water is pouring into and guarantee no spilled water. Instead, build your better bucket and put it next to the old one. Rather than managing the bucket, manage the water. When your new bucket is in place and you've confirmed it can hold water, direct the water flow to the new bucket. No lost water.

I may have butchered that analogy. Read up on [blue/green deployments](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) to gain a better understanding. In the end, Chef is going to provision the software on the machine but it's not going to manage web traffic at the network layer. Managing the traffic itself is the key to zero downtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I loved the way of your thinking about the situation/scenario.
So My understanding is that it is better to have an another identical application server as what is serving currently. 
Apply switch ON/OFF technique when we have to make a deployment with out downtime.

Let me analyze more in this way !! Thanks for the suggestion.